# sass @each loop with multiple lists

Tags: css, sass

developing in scss

I have the two variable lists:

```
$ids: 21, 33, 73;
$colors: #fff, #000, #333;
```

and the following @each loop.

```
@each $id, $color in ($ids, $colors) {
    .category--#{$id},
    .post--#{$id} {
       color: #{$color};
    }
}
```

I want to display the following

```
.category--21,
.post--21 {
    color: #fff
}

.category--33,
.post--33 {
    color: #000
}

.category--73,
.post--73 {
    color: #333
}
```

But I'm getting this instead

```
.category--21,
.post--21 {
    color: 33;
}

.category--#fff,
.post--#fff {
    color: #000;
}
```

Unsure of my structure. Obviously I have much longer variables lists (just added 3 to each one for demo purposes).

Any constructive feedback welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think `@each` is not the correct option for you as you don't have the key and value pair as one item.  Below is what the [documentation says about `@each`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-multi-assign): (emphasis is mine)

> The @each directive can also use multiple variables, as in @each $var1, $var2, ... in <list>. If <list> is a list of lists, ***each element of the sub-lists is assigned to the respective variable***.

As you can see from the above statement, in your case the `$ids` would be treated as one list and the `$colors` would be treated as another. It means that

- 1st iteration `$id` is `21`, `$color`  is `33` and `73` not assigned
- 2nd iteration `$id` is `#fff`, `$color` is `#000` and `#333` is not assigned.

---

It might be better for you to use the `@for` loop like in the below snippet:

```
$ids: 21, 33, 73;
$colors: #fff, #000, #333;

@for $i from 1 through length($ids) {
  $id: nth($ids, $i);
  $color: nth($colors, $i);
    .category--#{$id},
    .post--#{$id} {
       color: #{$color};
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that works really well as in development I may have less ids than colors. Perfect - thanks. +1

Comment: @twxia: Thanks a ton for the correction. I got it interchanged wrongly :)

Answer (score 3):

Hi you misuse it :D @each is iterate list by list see below

```
$pair: (21, #fff), (33, #000), (73, #333);

@each $id, $color in $pair {
    .category-#{$id},
    .post-#{$id} {
       color: #{$color};
       height: 20px;
    }
}
```

doc reference: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-multi-assign

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.. new it was me doing something wrong. However I went with @Harry solution as this works well with my development process. Thanks again. +1